# Roots of infinitely differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be an infinitely differentiable function that vanishes at $10$ distinct points in $\Bbb R$. Suppose $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $f$ , for  $n\ge1$. Which of the following statements is true ?

A. $f^{(n)}$ has at least $10$ zeros, for $1\le n\le8$

B. $f^{(n)}$ has at least one zero, for $1\le n\le9$

C. $f^{(n)}$ has at least $10$ zeros, for $n\ge10$

D. $f^{(n)}$ has at least $10$ zeros, for $n\ge9$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $x (x-1) (x-2) \cdots (x-9)$ which has degree $10$ and $10$ real roots: $0, 1, 2, \cdots, 9$. If you derive it exactly $10$ times, $f^{(10)} = 1$, which has no root, therefore C and D must be false. On the other hand, $f'$ is a polynomial of degree $9$ so, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, it may have at most $9$ roots, therefore A is false too.

Concerning B, forget now about the polynomial above and think about a generic function $f$. By [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), between any two consecutive zeros of $f$ there must be at least one zero of $f'$, so $f'$ may have at least $9$ zeros. Then $f''$ may have at least $8$ zeros, $f'''$ at least $7$ zeros and so on, up to $f^{(9)}$ which may have at least one zero. Therefore, B is true.

Answer (score 0):

By **Rolle's Theorem**, $f(x)$ has at least one point of inflection between any two of its roots. In other words, $f'(x)$ has atleast one root between any two roots of $f(x)$.

Using this statement, the correct option is (B)

As an explicit example, consider a degree $10$ polynomial with $10$ real roots.